# What is the importance of using WorkerThread annotation for a method that run in coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, worker-thread

I have noticed some methods in a project that I started to work recently as mentioned below. In this method functionality is executed in a coroutine. I wanted to know the purpose of the WorkerThread annotation here.

```
@WorkerThread
override suspend fun generate(context: Context) {
  return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // Some functionality
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [@WorkerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/WorkerThread) annotation indicates that the function should be called from a worker thread, be it for computational or timing reasons.

It will not prevent you from calling it from the main thread, but linters or code inspection tools will warn you if you do.

Answer (score 1):

By marking a method with the [`@WorkerThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/annotation/WorkerThread) annotation an author tells that
this method can take some time to execute and may freeze user interface(UI) so it should be running on a worker thread to prevent this.

Btw you can also mark a class with [`@WorkerThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/annotation/WorkerThread) annotation. In that case all methods in the class should be called on a worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

Given the above function is a suspend functions, there is no need to specify [@WorkerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/WorkerThread) annotation. Kotlin coroutines inherently support suspension and asynchronous execution. The suspension and resumption of a suspend function can happen on different threads and they are designed to be thread-agnostic.